# Как правильно подключить Allure в сочитании Python + Selenium + Unityest запустить сборку отчета?

Tags: python, selenium, юнит-тесты, selenium-webdriver, allure

Использую Python + Selenium webdriver + unittest framework. 
IDE: PyCharm.

Вот часть моего кода для тестирования калькулятора:

```
import unittest
import allure
from selenium import webdriver
import dop

class Testing(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        executable_path = "C:\Python37-32\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path)
        self.driver.get('http://XXXXXX')
        # self.driver.maximize_window()
        # self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)

    @allure.feature('Feature1')
    @allure.story('Story1')
    # Check first
    def test_is_button_1_valid(self):
        dop.check_button("/html/body/div[@class='buttons']/ul[@class='digits']/li[7]", "1", self)
        dop.check_input_field("1", self, False)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

P.S Я что-то пытался смастерить сам, но после десятков неудачных попыток - решил обратиться за помощью... Junior
P.P.S Можно ли мой код вообще интегрировать в jenkins?

При использовании скрипта для запуска:
python -m unittest D:/QA/untitled/first_test.py  --alluredir report
 ошибка:

```
python.exe -m unittest: error: unrecognized arguments: --alluredir report
```

Comment: а что конкретно не такк? 
выполните `python3 -m pytest Testing.py --alluredir ./results`, и после выполните `allure serve ./results/` , чтобы посмотреть результат.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor ошибка:  `python.exe -m unittest: error: unrecognized arguments: --alluredir report` ПРИ: `python -m unittest D:/QA/untitled/first_test.py  --alluredir report`

Comment: @SeniorPomidor или ошибка : `INTERNALERROR> AttributeError: module 'pytest' has no attribute 'allure'` при `python -m pytest D:/QA/untitled/first_test.py  --alluredir report
`

Comment: @SeniorPomidor помогло вот это: `pip uninstall pytest-allure-adaptor
pip install allure-pytest`

Comment: круто! можете оформить как ответ ваше решение. только не пишите одну команду и все

Answer (score 2):

- Установить Allure

  `pip install allure-pytest`
- Созать папку для загрузки временных результатов тестов:

  `pytest --alluredir reposts`
- Запуск тестов

  `python -m pytest D:/путь/к/файлу/tests.py  *--alluredir reports*`
- Формирование отчета:

  `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\allure serve D:\QA\untitled\report\`
  или

  `allure serve D:/путь/к/папке/reports/`

**Полезные ссылки:**
[Тестирование Python приложений используя PyTest](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/testing-python-applications-with-pytest), 
[Selenium + Python + Allure](https://qaboy.com/2018/01/08/setup-test-reports-selenium-using-python-allure/),
[Решение ошибки *module 'pytest' has no attribute 'allure'*](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-python/issues/58)